# Reading ArcGIS Online feature layer in ArcGIS Data Interoperability?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, fme-form, data-interoperability

I can't seem to read an ArcGIS Online feature service with Data interop. It's Build 15245-win32 and also have 10.3.1. Below is the Translation Log. I am trying to read the feature service and write the attributes it to a spreadsheet. There is only a reader connected to a writer. The URL for the service was automatically generated by the Add Reader tool but was shortened in this post.  Based on the log it was able to see the feature metadata but something happens when it gets the first 999 records. The ESRI account used was a publisher account.

```
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://services.arcgis.com/jWPB....../FeatureServer'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://services.arcgis.com/jWPB...../FeatureServer'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Found layer 'Deer Research Survey' with ID 0 for feature type 'Deer Research Survey'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Querying layer 0 for object IDs, where '1=1'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Got 2142 results for layer ID 0
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Splitting reading of 2142 features into 3 batches of up to 1000 features
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting feature results 0 to 999 of layer 'Deer Research Survey'
Python Exception <HTTPError>: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

As suggested below, I tried to reduce the number of records read but did not have success. Below is the log showing FME Configuration: Maximum of 10 feature(s) will be read starting from feature number 1, but it still tries for batches of 999.

```
Creating writer for format: 
Creating reader for format: 
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Will fail with first member reader failure
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Adding ARCGISONLINEFEATURES Reader with keyword ARCGISONLINEFEATURES_1
Using Multi Reader $Revision$ ( $Date$ ) with keyword `MULTI_READER' to read multiple datasets
Creating reader for format: Esri ArcGIS Online (AGOL) Feature Service
Trying to find a PYTHON plugin for reader named `ARCGISONLINEFEATURES'
FME Configuration: Maximum of 10 feature(s) will be read starting from feature number 1
FME Configuration: Maximum of 10 feature(s) will be read starting from feature number 1
Using FME's provided Python interpreter from C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\fmepython27\python27.dll
Python version 2.7 successfully loaded
Loaded Python module `arcgisonlinefeatures' from file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\plugins/python27\arcgisonlinefeatures\__init__.pyc'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Logging into 'http://sdgfp.maps.arcgis.com/' as user 'User.name'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting portal information
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in the root folder for user 'User.name'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Searching for all groups in the organization accessible to user 'User.name'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group '..........'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Found Feature Service item 'deerResearchCyberT' with ID 'e749f9cf879a43f993f0c431ebe0c826' for Feature Service directive '...../deerResearchCyberT'
Using MultiWriter $Revision$ ( $Date$ ) with keyword `MULTI_WRITER' to output data (ID_ATTRIBUTE is `multi_writer_id')
Writer output will be ordered by value of multi_writer_id
Loaded module 'LogCount_func' from file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\plugins/LogCount_func.dll'
FME API version of module 'LogCount_func' matches current internal version (3.7 20141021)
Creating writer for format: FME Feature Store (FFS)
FME Configuration: No destination coordinate system set
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://services.arcgis.com/jWPB..../arcgis/rest/services/deerResearchCyberT/FeatureServer'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://services.arcgis.com/jWPB..../arcgis/rest/services/deerResearchCyberT/FeatureServer'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Found layer 'Sightings' with ID 0 for feature type 'Sightings'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Querying layer 0 for object IDs, where '1=1'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Got 1922 results for layer ID 0
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Splitting reading of 1922 features into 2 batches of up to 1000 features
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting feature results 0 to 999 of layer 'Sightings'
Python Exception <HTTPError>: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include details about what you were trying to do, and how.  Have you tested the URL for the online service?  The message `<HTTPError>: 404 Client Error: Not Found` would indicate that it may not be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a bit of research I believe the 404 is not the correct error, instead it's really a 414: Request-URI Too Long

It appears to be a bug that was fixed in a later build. If you can update to at least build 15423 then the problem should be fixed. Sorry, I don't know how the Data Interop extension is supplied or packaged but basically you have the 2015 version and you need 2015.1

The only workaround I can think of is to check for the reader parameters, and see if you can set it to read only - say - the first 800 features.

Add another reader to read 801-1600, etc, etc. Not really a very elegant solution at all. I would definitely recommend upgrading if you are able.

Comment: I should also add that I may be wrong and it's not the cause. As @Midavalo suggests, it may actually be that the service isn't working. If it was a problem last week, then I think arcgis.com went down during the great S3 outage, so that could be a cause. Still, I'd say it's 80% likely it's this known issue, and it won't do any harm if you upgrade anyway.

Comment: The problem continues today so it wasn't related to the outage. I tried to set the reader parameters to only download 10 and the same thing happened. Next going to see if it will read a feature service with only a small number of records in it. Can I ask where you found the info about the bug?

Comment: OK I had success reading a feature service that only had 14 records total in it. Went back to my original service with the 1922 records and tried setting the params to only read 10 again. Start Feature 1, Max features to read 10, max features to read per feature type 10, min features to read [left blank]. Same error occurs. in fact it is still trying to make multiple batches of 999.

Comment: I work for Safe Software - the folk who developed the extension - and so I found that bug by browsing our developer database. Anyway, it looks like the workaround doesn't work, so I'm afraid I can't see another solution except to upgrade.

Comment: I am also getting same error i am running fme 2020 version.

Comment: Can you go to community.safe.com and register it there with our support team?